# Searching all users with a given post Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

If given a text, is there a way to find users which posted similar content on their walls.

I have tried "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=text&type=posts". But the results of this search contains a lot of random information of pages, groups, event where similar "text" was posted.
I want to omit the results of pages, groups & events and only want results of users. 
Is there a way of doing this in the Facebook graph api?